# React/Redux pre populating a form on a click

Tags: forms, reactjs, rendering, redux, updating

I'm trying to pre populate my form after clicking a button in my `Item` I have the actions to be able to update the item, the issue is being able to pre-populate the form with the correct item to be able to dispatch that action.

```
-----------------
| + List        | << Name of the list
-----------------
| SKU: 12345    | << Item
| ITEM: Bananas |
| PRICE: $1.00  |
|               |
| <edit>        | << Button triggering the modal and form. Need to pre-populate the form onClick
-----------------
```

/components/List.jsx

```js
export class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isModalOpen: false
    }
  }

  toggleModal () {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen })
  }

 ...

  render () {
    const { list, ...props } = this.props
    const listId = list.id

    return (
      ...

        <Items 
          items={props.listItems}
          openModal={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}>
        </Items>

        <Modal 
          className='list-add-item'
          openModal={this.state.isModalOpen}>
          <ItemForm 
            itemActions={this.props.itemActions} 
            listActions={this.props.listActions} 
            listId={listId}>
          </ItemForm>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

/components/ItemForm.jsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import uuid from 'node-uuid'

class ItemForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isEditing: false
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    let sku = this.refs.sku.value.trim()
    let text = this.refs.text.value.trim()
    let price = this.refs.price.value.trim()

    const item = { id: uuid.v4(), sku, text, price }

    // don't do anything if any field is left blank
    if (!item.sku || !item.text || !item.price) { return }

    this.props.itemActions.createItem(item)
    this.props.listActions.connectToList(this.props.listId, item.id)
    // reset the form after submission
    this.refs.itemForm.reset()
  }

  render() {
    const { ...props } = this.props

    return (
      <form ref="itemForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>SKU</label>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="SKU" 
            autoFocus={true}
            ref='sku'
            defaultValue={this.props.sku}
            onBlur={this.finishEdit}
            onKeyPress={this.checkEnter}></input>

          <label>Item</label>
          <input 
            type="text"
            placeholder="Item" 
            autoFocus={true}
            ref='text'
            defaultValue={this.props.text}
            onBlur={this.finishEdit}
            onKeyPress={this.checkEnter}></input>

          <label>Price</label>
          <input 
            type="text"
            placeholder="Price"
            autoFocus={true}
            ref='price'
            defaultValue={this.props.price}
            onBlur={this.finishEdit}
            onKeyPress={this.checkEnter}></input>

        <button type="submit">{ this.state.isEditing ? 'Edit Item' : 'Add Item' }</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default ItemForm
```

/components/Items.jsx

```js
export default class Items extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const {items, onEdit, ...props} = this.props

    return (
      <ul className='items'>{items.map((item) =>
        <Item
          className='item'
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          sku={item.sku}
          text={item.text}
          price={item.price}
          openModal={this.props.openModal}>
        </Item>
      )}</ul>
    )
  }
}
```

/components/Item.jsx

```js
export default class Item extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { openModal, ...props } = this.props

    return (
      <span>
        <li>SKU: {this.props.sku}</li>  
        <li>ITEM: {this.props.text}</li>
        <li>PRICE: {this.props.price}</li>
        <button onClick={this.props.openModal}>Edit Item</button>
      </span>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using redux-form instead, the way my app is setup it made it challenging to have fix the issue i was having. the working version is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706638/react-redux-redux-form-pre-populate-form-for-update/36728018#36728018)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing this. For example, you can follow these steps:

1. components/list: Add an internal state to know at every moment which item from the list is selected. Pass this `selectedItem` to the `itemForm` as props. Create a method `selectItem` that will update that state. Pass this `selectItem` method as props to your components/items. Remember to `bind` it to the component.
2. components/items: Add as an `onClick` handler, the `selectItem` passed as props to the component.
3. components/itemForm: In the `constructor` create a state with the information of the item passed in the props. Add the `willReceiveProps` and update the internal state of the component every time you receive some updated props with possibly a new selected item.

I hope you found this helpful and solves your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish the first part, I have a `listItems` array with all the `items` that belong to a `List`, how would you select just the right item out of that array? if it makes it easier for you to help we could pair on Screenhero @LlorençMuntaner

Comment: You can pass a function to `listItems` from `List` so that gets called `onClick` of an item. This function will be the responsible for updating the state in the parent.