# React/Redux Redux-Form Pre-Populate Form For Update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to pre-populate a form using the redux-form library. The issues I'm having now is being able to pass (perhaps) the `item.id` from the `Items` or `Item` component to the `List` when the `Edit Item` button is clicked. That way I could check it against my `listItems` array and grab it's data to populate the form. But prior to doing this, I created a function `populateForm` to try redux-form's `dispatch/initialize` function for "`populating`" the form. It works as expected, except that when I click `Add Item` the form never resets. I basically need two things done.

1. Get the logic going for selecting a single item and get it's data populated in the form so it can be edited.
2. figure why the form doesn't reset after it's populated on `Edit Item` click.

Thanks in advance.

/components/List.jsx

```
export class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isModalOpen: false
    }

    this.resetFrom = this.resetForm.bind(this)
  }

  toggleModal () {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen })
  }

  deleteList (listId, e) {
    e.stopPropagation()

    this.props.listActions.deleteList(listId)
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.props.reset('items')
  }

  createItem (item) {
    let items = {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      sku: item.sku,
      text: item.text,
      price: item.price
    }

    this.props.itemActions.createItem(items) 
    this.props.listActions.connectToList(this.props.list.id, items.id)
    this.resetForm()
  }
  // UPDATED
  populateForm (item) {
    const { id, sku, text, price } = item
    this.props.dispatch(initialize('items', {
      id, sku, text, price
    }, ['id', 'sku', 'text', 'price']))
  }
  // WAS THIS
  //populateForm () {
     //this.props.dispatch(initialize('items', {
      //sku: "Stuff",
      //text: "blah", 
      //price: "this"
    //}, ['sku', 'text', 'price']))
  //}

  render () {
    const { list, ...props } = this.props
    const listId = list.id

    return (
      <div {...props}>
        <div className='list-add-item'>
          <button onClick={this.toggleModal.bind(this, listId)}>+</button>
        </div>

        <div className='list-header'
          onClick={() => props.listActions.updateList({id: listId, isEditing: true})} >

          <Editor
            className='list-title'
            isEditing={list.isEditing}
            value={list.title}
            onEdit={(title) => props.listActions.updateList({id: listId, title, isEditing: false})}>
          </Editor>

          <div className='list-delete'>
            <button onClick={this.deleteList.bind(this, listId)}>x</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Items 
          items={props.listItems}
          // UPDATED
          populateForm={(item) => this.populateForm(item)}
          // WAS THIS
          // populateForm={(id) => this.populateForm({id, isEditing: true})}
          openModal={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}>
        </Items>

        <Modal 
          className='list-add-item'
          openModal={this.state.isModalOpen}>
          // UPDATED
          <ItemForm
            onEdit={this.props.itemActions.updateItem}
            onSubmit={this.createItem.bind(this)}>
          </ItemForm>
          // WAS THIS
          // <ItemForm onSubmit={this.createItem.bind(this)}/>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps (state, props) {
  return {
    lists: state.lists,
    listItems: props.list.items.map((id) => state.items[
        state.items.findIndex((item) => item.id === id)
    ]).filter((item) => item)
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    listActions: bindActionCreators(listActionCreators, dispatch),
    itemActions: bindActionCreators(itemActionCreators, dispatch),
    reset: bindActionCreators(reset, dispatch),
    dispatch: bindActionCreators(dispatch, dispatch)
  }
}

const { string, arrayOf, shape } = React.PropTypes

List.propTypes = {
  lists: arrayOf(shape({
    id: string.isRequired,
    title: string.isRequired
  }).isRequired)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List)
```

/components/Items.jsx

```
export default class Items extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const {items, openModal, populateForm, ...props} = this.props

    return (
      <ul className='items'>{items.map((item) =>
        <Item
          className='item'
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          sku={item.sku}
          text={item.text}
          price={item.price}
          // UPDATED
          populateForm={populateForm.bind(null, item)}
          // WAS THIS
          // populateForm={populateForm.bind(this)}
          openModal={openModal}>
        </Item>
      )}</ul>
    )
  }
}
```

/components/Item.jsx

```
export default class Item extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { openModal, populateForm, ...props } = this.props
    return (
      <span>
        <li>SKU: {this.props.sku}</li>  
        <li>ITEM: {this.props.text}</li>
        <li>PRICE: {this.props.price}</li>
        <button onClick={this.props.populateForm}>Edit Item</button>
      </span>
    )
  }
}
```

/components/ItemForm.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

class ItemForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { fields: {sku, text, price}, handleSubmit } = this.props

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <label>SKU</label>
        <input type="text" {...sku}/>

        <label>Item</label>
        <input type="text" {...text} />

        <label>Price</label>
        <input type="text" {...price} />

        <button type="submit">Add item</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ItemForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'items',
  fields: ['sku', 'text', 'price']
})(ItemForm);

export default ItemForm
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems that make this code hard to follow for me. I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. For example:

- `List.jsx` is calling `populateForm()` with `{id, isEditing: true}`, but `populateForm()` doesn't take any parameters.
- For some reason `Items.jsx` is binding `populateForm` to `this`. Why?
- `Item.jsx` is passing `populateForm` directly to `onClick`, so its parameter is going to be the event.
- `ItemForm.jsx`, in contrast, is flawless.

Comment: I have updated my `List.jsx` to reflect what i have working. At the time i had `isEditing` with another implementation and I guess I had left overs. My main issue was that i wasn't passing the item parameter to my populateForm, and I meant to bind item to the `Items.jsx` populateForm props. Now is it bad to have populateForm with 1. `...dispatch(initialize...` ? 2. is it bad to have the parameter from populateForm an event? if so what could be done? Thanks Erik R.